# CSS transform blur element on Galaxy S3 native browser

Tags: android, css, transform, samsung-mobile, samsung-galaxy-gear

In Samsung Galaxy S3 default browser (version 4.4.2)

[image]

Elements with a css3 transformation applied on appears crispy or blurry.

[image]

In that case it is a simple `translate`. Unit are in rem.

Using `transform3d` rather than simple `transform` has no effect. Replacing translate with a margin do the trick but I'd more likely keep the translate as I might animate it.

Is there a workaround which doesn't involve replacing everything with top, left absolute positionning or margin.

Thanks